# Shortest code for input

Tags: python, optimization, input, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a shortest code for input with condition as much as possible.
**Condition:** the number should be greater than 0.
**Input:** first number determines number of next inputs.
For example:

```
4
1
-2
3
-4
```

So i want to append to list() only 1 and 3.
Here is my code:

```
n=int(input())
t=[]
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    if(x>0):
        t.append(x)
print(t)
```

I'm wondering if it can be shorter
I had idea, but it was not working as i expected - "syntax error":

```
n=int(input())
t=[x=int(input()) for x in range(n) if(x)>0)]
print(t)
```

**EDIT:** forgot. I'm using python3.1...

Comment: This assignment, `x=int(input())`, cannot take place in a list comprehension.

Comment: OT: participating in http://codegolf.com/? :)

Comment: The extra parenthesis in your `if` statements are line noise.  See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the preferred formatting.

Comment: @Pavel I think to win in a codegolf you are contractually obligated to use perl ;)

Comment: @Voo I considered learning Perl for codegolf purposes!

Comment: @Pavel - definetly not. But i think i will participate ;d

Comment: @hradecek: If you are golfing, this problem will be shorter in Python 2 where `input` evaluates input.  Then your code could be `i=input;[x for x in[i()for _ in' '*i()]if x>0]`

Comment: @Steven:  Nice.  How about this for an evil variant...  `i=input;filter(range,map(i,['']*i()))`.  Or just `filter(range,map(input,['']*input()))`, which has the same number of characters, and doesn't need multiple statements.

Comment: @MarkDickinson:  Very nice.  I had tried `['']*input()` in some of my variations, but didn't get the savings because I did not think to use `range` as a filtering function.  Clever.

Comment: @MarkDickenson: I don't know much ruby, but here's how i would write it in that language: `gets.to_i.times.collect{gets.to_i}.find_all{|x|x>0}`.  It's not as short as the Python, but I like how it reads nicely left to right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
[x for x in (int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))) if x > 0]
```

Comment: He's using `input` to return a string which he casts to an integer, so he's using Python 3.  You'll need to cast the result of `input`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Oh didn't see that fixed.

Comment: Yep nested list comprehensions are great, although one has to be careful when using them - I looked at some code I wrote after "discovering" that feature.. well it doesn't necessarily improve readability. I'd say this is still ok though.

Comment: You're still forgetting one call to `int`, but +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda x: x > 0, (int(input()) for i in range(int(input()))))
```

Comment: `input` returns an string in Python 3, which is how he uses it in his answer.  Also he uses `print` as a function, which is another clue he's using Python 3.

Comment: Touche. Should have eyeballed the code a little more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Eugh....code golf. :)

You had misplaced parens in your shortest attempt. You can also shorten that up a bit (though not much) by using nested list comprehensions, like so:

```
t = [ x for x in [int(input()) for y in range(input())] if x > 0]
print t
```

the `range(input())` call doesn't need a cast to `int`, 'cause it will error anyway if `range` isn't passed an `int`.

Comment: Just as a note, it's convention to use `_` for unneeded parameters (often the case in range loops). Apart from having to think of additional names, this avoids IDEs complaining about unused parameters. Also using iterators instead of lists for the inner loop should be faster - or at least more memory effficient.

Comment: In Python 3, `input` always returns a string, so `range(input())` will fail for all inputs.

Answer (score -2):

```
print sum(max(0,input())for _ in range(input()))
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?